# Getting len of buffer for recv function

Tags: c++, sockets, pointers, char, recv

I wrote a simple FTP application that can send files back and forth between a client and a server and it was working fine. More recently I wrote a socket library to use with the client and server, some of the functionality has changed, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to get it to work. At the moment I'm integrating the library on my server.

The issue is that a part of my specs are to hide the socket handle with the library, so I've wrapped 'recv' and 'send' in library functions that pass a char pointer by reference. Before I implemented this I was passing char[] directly into the recv functions which was coming out nicely enough for my purposes. Now that I'm using a char* it would seem like I need to know the exact length of the incoming message as my char* is coming out with the send data as well as garbage characters.

Here is a part of my server code:

```
while (true)
{       
    command = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
    int bytesRecv = socketObject.receiveData('c', &command, 32);        

    if(_stricmp(command,"mput") == 0)
    {
        while( true ) {

             SizeCheck = 0;
             FileSize = 0;

             fileName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);                

             bytesRecv = socketObject.receiveData('c', &fileName, 1024);

             if(_stricmp(fileName,"goodbye") == 0)
             {                      
                break;
             }

            while( true )
            {
                char GotFileSize[1024];
                GotFileSize = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024); 
                socketObject.receiveData('c', &sentSize, 1024);


                FileSize = atoi(GotFileSize);

                if (FileSize > 0)
                {   
                    break;
                }
            }

            mfcc = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*FileSize);
            FILE *fp;
            if( (fp = fopen(fileArray, "wb")) == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "fopen has caused an error" << endl;
            }

            while(SizeCheck < FileSize){
                int Received = socketObject.receiveData('f', &mfcc, FileSize);              

                if(Received != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {   
                    std::cout << "Before fwrite" << std::endl;
                    int written = fwrite(mfcc, 1, FileSize, fp);
                    SizeCheck += Received;
                    fflush(fp);
                }   
            }//while transfer
        }//while true
    }//end mput if
```

Here is my receive function:

```
int Socket::receiveData( char socketType, char** data, int size)
{
if(socketType != 'f' && socketType != 'c')
{
    return -1;
}
if(socketType == 'f')
{
    int bytes = recv( fAccepted, *data, size, 0);
    return bytes;
}
else if(socketType == 'c')
{   
    int bytes = recv( cAccepted, *data, size, 0);
    if (bytes == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    return bytes;
}

return -1;
}
```

I've done some reading up on recv that tells me I should somehow either send the size of the filename with the filename, or compile a full string in a loop. I'm not sure if these methods are appropriate for what I'm attempting to do, or if there is an easier way.

Comment: You should use a `switch` in `receiveData`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly. Why are you passing a pointer to the data pointer instead of the data pointer itself? It is common practice in all kinds of C-style libraries to pass a buffer, and the size of the buffer, as function arguments, and have the function return the number of bytes that were actually written, or a negative error code.

Comment: Sounds like you've mis-designed it. The application should provide the buffer and its length.

Comment: The application should provide the buffer and its length in what way?

Comment: @CanadianCoder: Just look how `recv` does it: You pass to it the buffer, and the size of the buffer, and it returns the amount of bytes it has read. Your function should do it, and is actually already doing it, the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `receiveData` function is perfectly fine: It writes the received bytes to the buffer, and returns the number of bytes that were received.

All other bytes in the buffer can and should be ignored.
In your current code, each time you receive data, you're writing the **entire** buffer to the file, even though `receiveData` tells you precisely how much data you should write.

Namely, you shouldn't do

```
int written = fwrite(mfcc, 1, FileSize, fp);
```

but instead

```
int written = fwrite(mfcc, 1, Received, fp);
```

You should consider using a more reasonable buffer size, such as 1500 bytes (the usual MTU for network packets), or 1MB (something that should fit into the RAM without issues), instead of the full filesize.

By the way, there is no need to pass `data` as a double pointer, or, as you call it, as a reference to a pointer. Just pass it as a normal pointer. But that has nothing to do with your 'garbage data' issue.

Comment: I had the impression I needed to pass the buffer by reference through my library function. I found some pages that suggested passing a pointer to the pointer was the way to do it. Just started using pointers extensively this term and haven't wrapped my head around them yet!

Comment: You only need to pass your pointer by reference if you want the function to be able to modify the pointer itself. But your function only needs to modify the data pointed at by the pointer, so no need fo the reference.